# Ways to reach Hogwarts school of witchcraft and Wizardry?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, muggles

What are the various ways to reach Hogwarts School of witch craft and wizardry from the muggle world? Is Kings Cross Platform 9-3/4 the only way to reach Hogwarts from the Muggle world?